# 日本語に違和感: ユーザープロフィール > サマリー > 票の統計テーブルの文言

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: 投票テーブル]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 13件の票が入りました

13件の投票

> いつでも

通算

> 賛成

賛成票

> 月

今月

> 週

今週

> 日

今日